# UWP - Cards - Network game over local Wifi / Bluetooh, which Api use?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

I have developped a Windows 10 cards game (UWP application) and I want to add some features like that two people can play one against the other over Wifi or Bluetooth and I don't know what API to use to get a Socket or WCF Service and to discover other peer(s) which have the same application over the network ?

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question and there is no definitive ***"best way"*** to do it as each has their pros and cons, but here are a few links that may help you get started:

- Bluetooth comms sample
  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat
- UDP Multi-cast based game sample
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188201.aspx
- More on Bluetooth in UWP apps
  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-739